# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(k+1) \frac{e^{\sin(k)}}{e^{k}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(k+1) \frac{e^{\sin(k)}}{e^{k}}$$ converges.

Now, here's the thing. I have taken this exercise from a textbook, and this textbook wants you to do this without the ratio test, because the ratio test hasn't been introduced yet in this book up to this point. Essentially all I have is the **alternating series test**, which doesn't seem to be applicable here, and **direct comparison test** (and of course all of the convergence tests and rules for real  sequences in general, like if it's monotone and bounded or if it's a Cauchy sequence)

Any hints?

EDIT: Attempted solution with hints:

I know that $k^3 < e^k$ for all $k > 4 \cdot 3^2 = 36$. Then, if $k > 37$, we have $k^3 < e^{k-1}$, so we also have $$\frac{k}{e^{k-1}} < \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Then, by the direct comparison test $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{e^{k-1}}$$ converges, as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges. 
 Then, since $\log(k+1) < k$, we also have $$\frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k-1}} < \frac{k}{e^{k-1}}$$

Then, by the direct comparison test $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k-1}}$$ converges as well. Then, since $e^{\sin(k)} \leq e$, we also have

$$\frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k}} \cdot e^{\sin(k)} \leq \frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k}} \cdot e$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k}} \cdot e^{\sin(k)} \leq \frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k-1}}$$

Then, by the direct comparison test

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log(k+1)}{e^{k}} \cdot e^{\sin(k)} $$

converges.

Is this (somewhat) correct?

Comment: Oops: the textbook wants *you* to do this without the ratio test...

Comment: @amWhy I have been thinking about this for 2 hours, but without any further hints I don't think I'll be able to do this... It even took me a considerable amount of time to prove that the terms of the series are a null sequence

Comment: I'm simply trying to establish who "you" is in this case.  You've included background (what and what you haven't covered), stated the problem, and are asking only for hints, so I have not problem whatsoever with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINTS:**

For $k\ge 1$, we have

$$0< e^{\sin(k)}\le e$$

and

$$0<\log(1+k)\le k$$

and

$$\frac16 k^3<e^k$$

Comment: I used your hints to come up with a solution. Can you glance over it to see if it's correct?

Comment: Your reasoning  looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Use the fact that $$e^{\sin( k)}\le e$$
and

$$\lim_{k\to+\infty}k^2\ln(k+1)e^{-k}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

Simply  $\;\log(k+1)\dfrac{\mathrm e^{\sin k}}{\mathrm e^k}=o\biggl(\dfrac1{\mathrm e^{k/2}}\biggr)$ since $\;\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{\log(k+1)\,\mathrm e^{\sin k}}{\mathrm e^{k/2}}=0$, and the latter is a geometric series with ratio $\dfrac1{\sqrt e}<1$.